# Not able to call an action on Einstein Bot Builder

Tags: visual-workflow, einstein, bots

I have been trying to add an action to my Einstein bot with a flow that I have recently created. However, when ever I click on flows it always shows me "No Invocable Actions Found"

I am not sure on how I can see the flows that I have created with flow builder under the action options.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the @InvocableMethod to your class? Please check this link for more info.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bot_cookbook.meta/bot_cookbook/bot_cookbook_call_apex_action.htm